# Profiletool export error "global name 'os' is not defined"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, error, profile

I am using QGIS 2.18.5 and the Profiletool 4.0.2. plugin
I tried to save my profile to an .png file and this resulted with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\ui\ptdockwidget.py", line 567, in saveAs self.outPNG()
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\ui\ptdockwidget.py", line 587, in outPNG PlottingTool().outPNG(self.iface, self, self.mdl, self.cboLibrary.currentText ())
File "C:/Users/b/.qgis2/python/plugins\profiletool\tools\plottingtool.py", line 525, in outPNG wdg.profiletoolcore.loaddirectory = os.path.dirname(fileName)
NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

The same with exporting to .svg or .dxf

How can I fix it?

---

Profiletool 4.0.2. plugin (profile.py) itself already imports os:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import marshal
from optparse import OptionParser
```

However, I guess it is somehow correlated with it's predecessor - plottingtool.py which actually prints the error. The latter does not import os:

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *
import qgis


try:
    from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import *
except:
    pass


from . import resources
from .tools.profiletool_core import ProfileToolCore
```

Comment: Fails with the command "os.path.dirname"...have you tried importing os first?  (with the command:  import os)

Comment: I added more info above. Should I just type    import os
in the plottingtool.py? 
I tried and did not help. How should I import it?
I am totally blue as it comes to scripting.

Comment: Although I do not know how and why, the problem has been solved. The plugin works well after I reinstalled numpy and matplotlib due to another, unrelated issue.

Comment: Can you please add your last comment (with a bit more context) as an answer? I will upvote!